# External monitor stopped working (but all is ok on fresh install)

Tags: 20.04, display, 21.10

I have a problem with my Lenovo Thinkpad T14s (AMD!) stopped recognizing an external display connected with usb-c (not thunderbolt). It had Ubuntu 20.04.2 installed when this happened, and I have since updated to 21.04 and 21.10 with no change. Interestingly the display works fine when I install a new, fresh 21.10 on a new partition, so hardware failure is ruled out (in the fresh install, both x11 and wayland works fine).

I have googled and tried many suggestions, including most suggestions here on AskUbuntu that I thought relevant, but nothing helps. Since it works on a fresh install, my idea is that there must be some config and/or packages that are different, but I need help to figure out what can be wrong!

Comment: Does the workaround from another [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1946987) work in your case?

Comment: @jarno Thanks, but it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this here for reference.

Somewhere along the way the amdgpu driver was blacklisted. I simply deleted the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf` file, rebooted and everything works again.